# Meteor template not rendering in Chome DevTools Emulation mode

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm currently working in Chrome Emulation mode to Emulate an iphone 5. However, something strange is happening when in this mode. It happens ONLY in emulation mode and only on one route.The rest of the routes are rendering correctly.

Here is a simplified version of my code.

My layout:

```
<template name="layout">
    {{> header}}
    <div id="main">
        {{> yield}}
    </div>
    {{> footer}}
</template>
```

My relevant router.js:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('Lobby', {
    path : '/lobby',

    waitOn : function() {
      return [
        Meteor.subscribe('gameList', this.params._id),
        Meteor.subscribe('gameInfo', this.params._id),
        Meteor.subscribe('userNames', this.params._id)]
    },

    data : function() {

    }
  });
})
```

My lobby template:

```
<template name="Lobby">

    {{#if currentUser}}

    {{#if countGames}}
    <div class="findGame"><h3>Bring the action!</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-orange btn-outlined findGame-js">Find a Game!</button>
    </div>
    {{else}}
    <ul class="table-view" id="list-games">
        <br/>
        {{#each activeGame}}
        {{> gameInfo}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
    {{/if}}

    {{else}}
    <h4>Login or create account to continue</h4>
    {{/if}}


</template>
```

And my Lobby helpers:

```
Template.Lobby.helpers({

  countGames : function() {
    userId = Meteor.userId();
    return 0 === Games.find({$or : [
      {theBoss : userId},
      {thePlayer : userId}
    ]}).count();

  },

  activeGame : function() {
    userId = Meteor.userId();
    return Games.find({$or : [
      {theBoss : userId},
      {thePlayer : userId}
    ]});

  }
})
```

If i go to the specified router using:

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'Lobby'}}"><h4>Title</h4></a>
```

The resulting page on the url will be empty. The  is completely empty. IF I refresh the page the page will be rendered correctly. Is this just a bug of chrome or is this something where I have to worry about?